# Reinventing the Wheel: C# Webforms Content Management System

Tags: c#, web-applications, webforms, content-management

We need a content management system, but we need alot of features that are not available on the market now: integration with Azure AD, integration with our phone system, and a couple others.

I'm having an issue figuring out how to implement a basic feature: allowing the user to add pages to their directory.

Here's my question: Should I literally write a new .aspx file to the directory, or should all of my pages and their content be stored in a SQL Database?

Comment: "we need a lot of features that are not available on the market now".  This is almost always a sign you haven't looked hard enough; either at what's on the market, or at your requirements.

Comment: And there's no reason to rewrite an entire CMS just because they don't have one feature. Start with one with open/modifiable source and go from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, storing any kind of data directly into your filesystem ends up being very crude and primitive because the filesystem itself has a limited set of data management tools (whatever the O/S provides and then any 3rd-party tools which will probably require the command-line, and may require elevated privileges on the host), a fairly fixed rigid structure for creating relationships between data/files (e.g. a file can't belong to multiple directories), and a fairly limited ability to add metadata (You'd probably have to model all of that yourself in another file, or come up with a clever file naming schema).

Databases tend to provide a lot of tools for managing data - for example, redundancy, scalability, backup tools, security, etc.

Also consider any metadata that you might wish to store - for example, you might consider providing a 'version' or timestamp field in a database alongside your users' content, so that they can save changes without overwriting their historical content (and therefore have the ability to undo/rollback).

Lastly, consider the Portability aspect of storing your users' data using the `aspx` format - Standard HTML is inherently portable across many systems, but using aspx as your data storage format prevents that data from being used in a different environment, and also prevents your users from being able to take a copy of their HTML and edit it in some other external HTML tool.

Answer (score 2):

"Reinventing the wheel" is right!!!! and why oh why webforms??!??

Spare yourself the pain and use something off the shelf. Sharepoint? (shudder)

Just write a couple of micro services to do the auth and phone system stuff if you really really have to.

Comment: As much as I hate to say it, it does sound like a SharePoint site that OP is describing.